# Find a finite subgroup of order at least $6$ from an infinite non-abelian group which every element is of order less than $6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite non-abelian group such that for all $g\in G$, $1\leq |g|\leq 5$.
Prove or disprove that there exists a finite subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $|H|\geq 6$.

By the assumption, first we know that if $H$ exists, $H$ must not be cyclic.
Secondly, if $g^2=1$ for every $g\in G$, then $G$ is abelian; a contradiction.
Hence there exists $g\in G$ such that $3\leq|g|\leq 5$.

Yet the two information are not sufficient to prove or disprove the statement.

Comment: Maybe this is overkill, but it seems closely related to the Burnside problem.  In particular, if we were given that every element has order dividing $n$ for a single value of $n \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 6\}$, then the finiteness of $B(m, n)$ for all $m$ would imply that every finitely generated subgroup is finite, which would prove the result.  But we might have problems with elements of order 5, or groups with nonidentity elements of multiple different orders.

Comment: The wording of this problem is slightly confusing, and I am unsure exactly what we are trying to prove.  Certainly there exist infinite nonabelian groups with exponents 3 and 4, and they do indeed have finite subgroups of order at least 6. Does that answer the question?  Or are we supposed to prove that finite subgroups of order at least 6 exist in all groups with this property? But that might be difficult, because it is still unknown whether there exist Tarski Monsters of exponent  $5$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I wish to prove that finite subgroups of order at least $6$ always exist in all groups with this property.

Comment: Well to prove that, you will need to prove that Tarski Monsters of exponent 5 do not exist, which would probably win you a Fields Medal if you are under 40 - [see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138368/) Were you asked to prove this as an exercise?

Comment: @DerekHolt No, this is a tool that I wish to use in proving a result of my research. Then I might need to consider other tools for my research.

Comment: @DerekHolt "probably get a Fields medal" (for proving non-existence): well, this is Mark Sapir's claim in the comments there, but... a number of people (some time agi) have thought seriously about groups of exponent 5, failing to determine whether infinite. But have they thought about existence of a Tarski monster? I guess not. Sapir might have thought seriously anyway, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

*(I'm posting cw since I partly copy feedback from Derek Holt)*

---

It is a notoriously hard old problem whether the Burnside group $B(2,5)$ is infinite (equivalently, whether there exists an infinite 2-generated group of exponent 5).

It is also open whether there exists a Tarski monster of exponent 5, that is, an infinite 2-generated group of exponent 5 satisfying the additional condition: every pair either is contained in a cyclic subgroup, or generates the whole group. This question was asked [here at Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138368/tarski-monster-group-with-prime-5) in 2013. If the OP's question has a positive answer (that is every infinite torsion group with all elements of order $<6$ has a finite subgroup of order $|6|$), then a negative answer follows (which is weaker than proving that $B(2,5)$ is finite). Hence it seems hard to prove a positive answer.

And it would be definitely hard to prove a negative answer, as it would imply that the Burnside group $B(2,60)$ is infinite (indeed let $G$ be a counterexample: take two non-commuting elements, so they generate a subgroup of order $\ge 6$, hence infinite, and the exponent divides $\operatorname{lcm}(2,3,4,5)=60$). Because of the additional constraints, it's even much more than just proving $B(2,60)$ is infinite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I wish to find an infinite subgroup of infinite index from a group with the condition stated in the question? Will it be related to burnside problem too?

Comment: @AlanWang Well Tarski monsters really have the property that all proper subgroups are finite. So proving that an infinite subgroup of infinite index exists seems of similar difficulty.